# How to get byte[ ] from BitmapSource where byte array length is equal to BitmapSource's width x BitmapSource's height

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmap

I am writing an application that requires the conversion of BitmapSource to byte array of pixels. Byte array's length should be equal to Bitmap's width x Bitmap's height.

I have tried bmp.CopyPixels() function in the namespace System.Windows.Media.Imaging. But it output an array which is larger than width x height of bitmap.

```
private byte[] GetBytesFromBitmapSource(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource bmp)
        {
            int width = bmp.PixelWidth;
            int height = bmp.PixelHeight;
            int stride = width * ((bmp.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);
            byte[] pixels = new byte[height * stride];
            bmp.CopyPixels(pixels, stride, 0);
            return pixels;
        }
```

My image (BitmapSouce) size is 2686 x 2686. I am expecting a pixel array having length 2686 x 2686 . (byte[2686 x 2686])

Comment: The stride should be rounded up to the nearest four-bite boundary.

Comment: Sounds great :-)